# angular.js (or knockout.js) integration with other UI libraries?

Tags: data-binding, knockout.js, angularjs

I am going to use either knockout.js or angular.js libs (b/c of the binding support) for a web app.

My question is - how is your experience integrating these libs into existing UI libs like Dojo, jQueryUI, Ext.js, YUI,..
E.g. how is the usage of databinding suport/syntax in the UI libs? Do you have to implement something like custom binding in order to use the widget form UI lib?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For **Knockout** the situation is quite good. One can integrate with third-party widgets via [custom bindings](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html). Bindings API is very simple and strait-forward. All you need is to implement one or two methods (quoting Knockout docs):

```
ko.bindingHandlers.yourBindingName = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
        // This will be called when the binding is first applied to an element
        // Set up any initial state, event handlers, etc. here
    },
    update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
        // This will be called once when the binding is first applied to an element,
        // and again whenever the associated observable changes value.
        // Update the DOM element based on the supplied values here.
    }
};
```

Most of the time implementing single `update` method is sufficient. There's even [a collection of ready-made bindings for **jQuery UI**](https://github.com/madcapnmckay/Knockout-UI). It doesn't cover all jQuery UI widgets but since creating custom bindings is so simple you can implement your own bindings as you see need.

As for **Angular JS** the situation is more difficult. You can create a custom binding as a part of your own [Directive](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive). Directives API requires you to write much more code. The lifecycle of directives is quite complex, too. So, they would take quite a bit of time to learn.

At the same time it lets you specify a lot of different aspects of behavior. For example you can completely rewrite the inner HTML representation of a widget via `directive` and use Angular templates inside. In Knockout you'd need to use jQuery for that. Unfortunately, unlike custom bindings in Knockout directives are more suitable for writing your own widgets and not for integrating with existing ones.

To summarize:

- Knockout bindings are easier. Integrating with third-party widgets is easy.
- Angular directives are more suitable for writing your own widgets but are more powerful at the same time.

Comment: Also note that Angular's site is currently in a flux so a lot of links from discussions are broken. I would really love to give you a more specific example for Angular integration wit jQuery, or Ext JS, or some other library but I can't find anything :(

Comment: An offshoot group of angularjs called angular-ui (of which i am a member) is in process of creating angular widgets, wrapping jqueryui and twitter bootstrap plugins. It is in early stages and we do need to rev-up to the newly released 1.0 of angularjs. It is true that there is more complexity with using angular directives. Angular's strengths are numerous the biggest hurdle for most is notifying angular that the model has changed so that it can reflect in the view.

Comment: @DanDoyon The Angular-ui library is useful, for sure, but is lacking in a lot of areas as well.  To answer the OP's question, integrating Angular into an existing app is not possible.  Integrating Knockout is.  Angular is all or nothing, Knockout is not.

Comment: @PWKad, Its been a while since, i've commented. Since then google has taken on coordinating with angular-ui and came up with angular native code replacements to bootstrap. In regards to the comment about all or nothing. I cannot speak to Knockout, but it is possible to target only part of a pages DOM with Angular. I've used this technique with ASP.NET a while back and it worked fine. And the biggest thing about angular is when integrating with other libraries, because of the 2way binding, you need to do scope.apply to notify angular to run its digest cycle to handle the change.

Answer (score 2):

Typically you would implement custom bindings to work with external libraries, but there are often plenty of open source efforts that have already made considerable headway. Check out

https://github.com/SteveSanderson/knockout/wiki/Bindings

If there aren't any available, implementing your own isn't terribly complicated:

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html